# Migrating nullable json column in EF Core to non-nullable

Tags: c#, entity-framework, npgsql

I am trying to migrate a previously nullable json column to a non-nullable column in EF Core using a PostgreSQL 16 database.
The generated MigrationBuilder fragment looks like this:

```cs
migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
   name: "preferences",
   schema: "myschema",
   table: "mytable",
   type: "json",
   nullable: false,
   defaultValue: "",
   oldClrType: typeof(string),
   oldType: "json",
   oldNullable: true);
```

This of course does not work since an empty json column requires at least `'{}'`, `''` is not a valid value.
I changed above code to `defaultValue: "{}"`, but the SQL generated by EF when running the migration still tries to update `null` values to `''`. The migration still fails even after manually making sure that there are no actual `null` values left in the database.
The error is

```
Failed executing DbCommand (5ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
UPDATE myschema."mytable" SET preferences = '' WHERE preferences IS NULL;
ALTER TABLE myschema."mytable" ALTER COLUMN preferences SET NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE myschema."mytable" ALTER COLUMN preferences SET DEFAULT '{}';
Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 22P02: invalid input syntax for type json
```

Is there any way i can tell EF to skip updating existing null values?

Comment: Try marking your entity configuration with `HasDefaultValue("{}")`, this should be picked up by the migration generation.

Comment: Throw in your own `migrationBuilder.Sql()` to update the values? The migration won't set any `NULL` to `''` if there aren't any...

Comment: Looks like a bug that has already been fixed? https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/issues/2965

Comment: Or maybe do it in two steps? First add the default then set not null

Answer (score 0):

I guess in my case there was some sort of caching going on. Tried it again today after rebooting my machine and the issue was gone. I ended using the suggested `migrationBuilder.Sql()` approach to update all affected entries.